# Cannot export using three.js with blender 2.69

Tags: three.js, blender

i'm trying to install `three.js` imports add on on `blender 2.69`, i'v tryed to copy the `io_mesh_threejs` into my `~/config/blender/2.69/script/addons` but no entry in my blender addon menu.

I then move the `__init__.py` file there :

```
io_mesh_threejs into my ~/config/blender/2.69/script/
```

and then i have the entry menu, that i then select.

i tryed to export the basic cube to test it, but i have an error message :

```
.../init__.py", line 336, in execute import io_mesh_threjs.export_three.js
importError:No module named'io_mesh_threejs'
location:<unknow location>
```

---- my solution -----

I'm not sure it's the right way, but anyway, i copy the init.py and the 2 other file (import and export one) and put them dirctly on the addon repertory : /usr/share/blender/(...)/addons/

as it seems not to find the io_mesh_threejs i then change the line 336 and 337 of the __init.py file as this :

```
import export_threejs
return export_threejs.save(self, context, **self.properties)
```

it seems to work as i've now a threejs-test.js (the name i gave when saving) file in my personal dirctory, and when i open that file i've got an object.

i then trid the import module, it seems that the same tweak had to be done on line 146.

Now export and imports work

if it can help.

i then try to copy the directory `io_mesh_threejs` in the modules' one but noting better, as well as moving `__init__.py` on `the /usr/share/blender/.../addon` one

i read that people succed in using this plugin with 2.69,  so i'm looking for help, thanks by advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Instead of messing with the files i just restarted blender. That worked for me. Not sure why you had to change the files.